# Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument / Invalid data

Tags: ffmpeg

this code was running in 2020 and prior years. now not. nothing changed.
(I suspect that maybe something wrong windows.these code was adding fadein and fadeout effect into video in prior years. now not working... nothing changed. but maybe some dll confliction in my system.)

Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument / Invalid data found when processing input

```
-filter_complex [1:v]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0,50,fade=in:st=1:d=5:alpha=1,fade=out:st=46:d=5:alpha=1[tagovr];[0:v][tagovr]overlay=W-w-0:H-h-0:shortest=1[tagmerged];[tagmerged]fade=in:st=0:d=3,fade=out:st=49:d=3 -c:a copy
```

have you any idea?

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: thanks sir! with the report and verbose log I found the problem. because of religional settings. decimal seperator should be point
colorchannelmixer=aa=0,50 should be
colorchannelmixer=aa=0.50